# PHPExcel generate data to array from defined sheet

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to generate an array from my xlsx file first, before I insert it to Mysql, so I am using phpexcel because this one is good enough (I know it from every website's review). But there is a problem when I am trying to making an array from the xlsx defined sheet, here is my script :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Automatic Importer</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>PHPExcel Reader Example #07</h1>
<h2>Simple File Reader Loading a Single Named WorkSheet</h2>
<?php

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


//$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
    $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2003XML';
//  $inputFileType = 'OOCalc';
//  $inputFileType = 'Gnumeric';
$inputFileName = 'file.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'My Sheet 4';

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
echo 'Loading Sheet "',$sheetname,'" only<br />';
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


echo '<hr />';

echo $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(),' worksheet',(($objPHPExcel->getSheetCount() == 1) ? '' : 's'),' loaded<br /><br />';
$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);


?>
<body>
</html>
```

and this is the error says :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function cellExists() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\chi\import\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 3241
```

Can someone tell where is the error is? My OOP is not good, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is something in one of the spreadsheet formulae that PHPExcel is having problems evaluating, when you call toArray() with the 3rd argument as TRUE telling the method to evaluate all the formulae in the worksheet. I did add a fix to this last night where a named range containing a reference to a non-existent cell is used in a formula... a bug that would trigger this message; but in this case (with the error at that particular line number) it looks as though it could be a formula that references a non-existent worksheet. The fact that you're only loading a single named worksheet makes this quite possible.

If possible, can you "walk the spreadsheet", using getCalculatedValue() on each cell to find which cell contains the  formula that is triggering the error; and then see what that formula is?

Alternatively, load the entire workbook rather than just the one individual worksheet, and see if the error still occurs then.

I'll look at patching the calculation engine code to prevent this error; but it does mean that the formula can't be correctly evaluated if a sheet that it references isn't accessible.

Comment: Hi mark, I just read your answer in another people's question. Can you tell me why is this error? link : http://pastebin.com/c5VFX4z2 . I think the error is happening in 'rangeToArray', thanks

Comment: aah, it's fixed sir, thanks. But why every php excel class (like phpexcel or simplexlsx) is always had " Out of memory " problem? That's made me crazy, I have try everything on my head but it isn't solved :(

Comment: @Have you tried using any of the cell caching methods to reduce the memory demands?

Comment: Reading section 4.2.1 of the Developer documentation (entitled "Cell Caching") should help get you started

Comment: Wow, ok, I'll learn for it thanks. Btw is there any another way to make the data from xlsx to an array?

Comment: How do you mean, "another way"? PHPExcel provides a simple method called toArray(), or you can iterate through all the rows and cells building your own array by calling getValue() for each individual cell

Comment: I mean, I want the Array is structured like this : [col][row], it is better I think

Comment: In that case, you'll have to iterate through the worksheet yourself and build the array, or you'll have to rotate the matrix yourself

Comment: Ok, btw I have trying ur suggest to try caching cell. I think the best is "cache_to_discISAM", the "tried to allocate" is reduced to 36 bytes. What can I do next? I think that is the best of caching that I can do for now :-/

Comment: Other options: increase the memory you allow, use the SQLite caching (which is the most memory efficient); don't use toArray() because the array that's created consumes a lot of memory (iterate through the rows and columns manually)

Answer (score 0):

You could start by setting up Xdebug, that will give clearer picture where the error is coming from. From this code, I can assume, that xlsx file doesn't get read due to some error or there's some problem with sheets that are supposed to be read.

Comment: I iam now thinking that the error is not from reading, but I think the problem is how to make it to an array?